# Uninfinite async function execution in next js

Tags: async-await, next.js

I'm new to next js. And I have one user.js file inside of my pages directory in next.js. This is the source code:

```
// pages/user.js
 function user(props) {
      const [userList, setUserList] = useState([])
      const [roleList, setRoleList] = useState([])
    
      async function initialFetch() {
        const userList = await fetch('GET', GET_ALL_USERS)
        setUserList(userList)
    
        const roleList = await fetch('GET', GET_ALL_ROLES)
        setRoleList(roleList)
    
        console.log('userList in async')
        console.log(userList)
      }
      
    
      if (!props.userList.status) {
        initialFetch()
      } else {
        setUserList(props.userList)
        setRoleList(props.roleList)
      }
    
      console.log('userList outside')
      console.log(userList)
      
      return (
      <>
        <TableUserManagement users={userList} roles={roleList}/>
      </>
      )
 };
    
 user.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
      const userList = await fetch('GET', GET_ALL_USERS)
      const roleList = await fetch('GET', GET_ALL_ROLES)
      return {userList, roleList}
    }
```

The problem is that above async initialFetch() function is always called uninfinitively :
[image]

So what am I doing wrong here? Thank you

Note: I have tried to use useEffect() but the looping still happening. This the code :

```
 useEffect(
    () => {
      if (!props.userList.status) {
        initialFetch()
      } else {
        setUserList(props.userList)
        setRoleList(props.roleList)
      }
      console.log('user list diliuar')
      console.log(userList)
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is not related to Next.js but React itself. This is the code that cause unfinite calls:

```
if (!props.userList.status) {
  initialFetch()
} else {
  setUserList(props.userList)
  setRoleList(props.roleList)
}
```

Since after setting any state, your component re-renders and that part of code keeps running again, and the fetch cause setting state again,... that loops forever.

You should move you data-fetching logic in side `componentDidMount` or `useEffect`. Remember to provide the dependency array of `useEffect`. In this case, you may only need to fetch data only once so you should provide the empty dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function initialFetch() {
    const userList = await fetch('GET', GET_ALL_USERS)
    setUserList(userList)

    const roleList = await fetch('GET', GET_ALL_ROLES)
    setRoleList(roleList)
  }
  

  if (!props.userList.status) {
    initialFetch()
  } else {
    setUserList(props.userList)
    setRoleList(props.roleList)
  }
}, []);
```

P/s: you should name you React component in PascalCase (ex: User)

Comment: btw, is there any way around instead of using useEffect or componentDidMount? because those 2 ways will be called after page is rendered but because I wanna fetch the data when the page is loading or something like getInitialProps is executed :)

Comment: oowh btw. I just tried to use useEffect but the uninfinite loop still happenings

Comment: Hi @MaryadiPoipo, I've updated the sample code. For the case that you want the data to be ready before the page rendering and mounting, `getInitialProps` will enable server-side rendering, in which you fetch the data from the server and provide them as props for the page component to render and return to the browser.

Comment: For the case of fetching data from the client side, this article may help you: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data